# Fluent NHibernate paralysis - Need clean example

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Ive been trying to get NHibernate up and running and I driving myself insane with what to do in terms of the repository pattern and unit of work pattern. Are there any examples out there that uses both and is clean and easy to understand? Ive looked at so many i cant seem to put anything together that works.

Comment: The question isn't related to Fluent...but it might help if you think of the UnitOfWork as a wrapper/abstraction of the ISession and ITransaction so your high level code doesn't need to know about NH.

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes after posting this I found a couple of projects that have been extremely helpful. Maybe this can help a few other out there as well.

http://ncommonsample.codeplex.com/

http://ncommon.codeplex.com/